# How to query all columns with an id from another table?

Tags: javascript, orm, sequelize.js

I am fairly new to sequelize and have come across a problem which I haven't found any documentation for.

I have three tables/models in my code:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const country= sequelize.define(
        'country',
        { name: DataTypes.STRING }
        }
    );
    country.associate = function(models) {
        country.hasMany(models.city, { foreignKey: 'countryId' });
    };
    return country;
};
```

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const city = sequelize.define(
        'city',
        {
            countryId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            name: DataTypes.STRING,
        }
        }
    );
    city.associate = function(models) {
        city.belongsTo(models.country, { as: 'country' });
        city.hasMany(models.venue, { foreignKey: 'cityId' });
    };
    return city;
};
```

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const venue= sequelize.define(
        'venue',
        {
            cityId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            name: DataTypes.STRING,
        }
        }
    );
    venue.associate = function(models) {
        venue.belongsTo(models.city, { as: 'city' });
    };
    return venue;
};
```

Country -> City -> Venue.

My question is: Is there any way to query all the venues in a certain country?

For example:
Countries table:

```
+----+---------+--+
| id |  name   |  |
+----+---------+--+
|  1 | Canada  |  |
|  2 | USA     |  |
|  3 | Austria |  |
+----+---------+--+
```

Cities table:

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| id |  name   | countryId |
+----+---------+-----------+
|  1 | Ottawa  |         1 |
|  2 | Toronto |         1 |
|  3 | Chicago |         2 |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

Venues table:

```
+----+------+--------+
| id | name | cityId |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | V1   |      1 |
|  2 | V2   |      1 |
|  3 | V3   |      2 |
|  4 | V4   |      3 |
+----+------+--------+
```

How would I query all the venues in Canada, to get V1 V2 V3?

Comment: Join the 3 tables.

Comment: You haven't found any documentation? Any SQL tutorial should explain how to do simple joins like this.

Comment: Sequelize documentation doesn't explain this

Comment: Here's the first hit when I google "sequelize join" https://lorenstewart.me/2016/09/12/sequelize-table-associations-joins/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, you can join the tables by `include` in sequlize :

```
// To get venues from country id
venue.findAll({
    include : [
        {
            model : city
            where : {
                countryId : YOUR_COUNTRY_ID
            }
        }
    ]
})

// To get venues from country name
venue.findAll({
    include : [
        {
            model : city
            include : [{
                model : country
                where : {
                    name : YOUR_COUNTRY_NAME
                }
            }]
        }
    ]
})
```

> Note :
>
> `model : YOUR_MODEL_NAME` , as per your code I have assume that you
>   are using same name venue,city and country for model, or else you have
>   to change that as per your code.